# Looping through array containing arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have completely changed the format of my array now, and I had what I hope is a simple misunderstanding on my part.  So my array now looks like the following

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "leadData" => array:7 [▼
      "LeadID" => "1232806"
      "Client" => "Some Client"
      "LeadName" => "Test"
      "Owner" => "Someone"
      "Value" => "2160.00"
    ]
    "clientData" => array:2 [▼
      "Prospect" => "No"
    ]
    "quoteData" => array:8 [▼
      "QuoteID" => "Q0020"
      "ProjectName" => "Test"
      "Amount" => "1234"
    ]
    "customData" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "Type" => "New"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "Month" => "June 16"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
     ...
  ]
]
```

So it is essentially now 4 inner arrays.  Now if I do the following, I can print out all the data for the leadData inner array

```
foreach($leadArray as $array)
    <tr>
        foreach($array['leadData'] as $leadKey => $leadData)
            <td>
                {{ $leadData }}
            </td>
        endforeach
    </tr>
endforeach
```

That works fine.  However, I only want to display certain parts of this array.  I would have presumed doing something like the following would work

```
foreach($leadArray as $array)
    <tr>
        foreach($array['leadData'] as $leadKey => $leadData)
            <td>
                {{ $leadData['LeadID'] }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $leadData['LeadName'] }}
            </td>
        endforeach
    </tr>
endforeach
```

However if I do this I get and Illegal String Offset error.  Is this not how I would access this data?

p.s. Ignore the way I do the foreach loop etc, this is because I am using a template engine.

Thanks

Comment: you mix with object array and associative array. you can try: `$leadData->LeadID`

Comment: How can I identify object array vs associative array?

Comment: first you use the `print_r` to show the array.

Comment: In your question mention what you really want??????????

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop over the second array, you can use the keys to get the data.

```
foreach($leadArray as $array)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $array['leadData']['LeadID'] }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $array['leadData']['LeadName'] }}
        </td>
    </tr>
endforeach
```

Comment: That works to a point, it then complains Undefined index: quoteData

Comment: When trying to display data on another level, you have to replace the `leadData`. For example: `$array['quoteData']['QuoteID']`.

Comment: @kate_hudson, if it is works then your array is associative, so you have to use your logic to show all the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your main array will be like this, where you want to work, right?
<pre>
$aMainArray = array(
    0 => array(
        "leadData" => array(
            "LeadID" => "1232806",
            "Client" => "Some Client",
            "LeadName" => "Test",
            "Owner" => "Someone",
            "Value" => "2160.00",
        )
    )
);
foreach ($aMainArray AS $aSubArray) {
    print_r($aSubArray);
    // You can echo your required values like below
    echo $aSubArray['leadData']['LeadID'];
    echo $aSubArray['leadData']['LeadName'];
    // OR like this one
    foreach ($aSubArray AS $value) {
      echo $value['LeadID']; 
      echo $value['LeadName'];
    }
}
</pre>
```

Comment: please review my edited answer.. and if you find it fruitful then please vote me.